# Literary Device for speech like: "I, ___"

Tags: meaning

Basically, is there a Literary Device or term for when a character or person goes (for example), "I, gifted with wisdom", "I, the one whom grants wishes" or "I, Peter Jordan the Third"

Thanks.

Comment: I would say "apposition" but that is not a literary device, it is just an ordinary part of English grammar.

Comment: What in the world is that *whom* whooming?! Don't follow it with a verb; that's ungrammatical.

Comment: I feel that I have given a correct answer here, that is currently marked as -2 ew ew 

Answer (score -2):

I would say it's 'personification' because the person is identifying themselves as the 'one who does x, y, or z'.

Note that 'personification' can be 'with a concept' - as in this case (explained below).

For example 'I, Flash Gordon, saviour of the Universe' has 'personified himself' as 'saviour of the Universe'.

If I said: I, Jelila, maker of the best cupcakes, cupcake queen...

I have 'personified' myself as 'queen of cupcakes'.

I have said 'I am that thing' so I have 'personified myself' as it, or with it.

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=personification+definition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

You can personify yourself as an inanimate object, or as a concept, as in the example in this question where for example 'I am gifted with wisdom' personifies the person with the concept of 'wisdom'.

Here is an article explaining *personification with a concept*:

https://www.dailywritingtips.com/personification-vs-anthropomorphism/

Comment: You have that back to front - I'm pretty sure. Personification is inanimate objects being treated as having human characteristics. Re-read the article you linked to. The last example I saw in fiction had a person sitting on a dead tree trunk ... The tree trunk thought, "That's okay."

Comment: @Ross Murray Personification is when you *identify yourself with something*, I believe. It could be an inanimate object like a treetrunk, or it could be a concept (which is also kind of 'inanimate', if you think about it) - like 'greatest  cupcake maker' or 'saviour of the Universe'.  I have modified my answer to explain this.

Comment: Actually @RossMurray it appears that your 'treetrunk' example is 'anthropomorphism' - where something inanimate takes on human attributes - the link I added to my expanded answer explains that in detail, as well.